# I'm watching Let's make a game together ep10 but the door part don't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class GoToNewArea : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject sp1, sp2;

    void Start ()
    {
        sp1 = this.gameObject;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D trig) 
    {
        trig.gameObject.transform.position = sp2.gameObject.transform.position;
    }
}
```

The video : https://youtu.be/8Zwh2X6BCEk

The "door" don't do anything(The player should change position to sp2, even with the print nothing show up. What I'm I doing wrong? The code is the exact same thing (I think) but it don't work. I need help and I'm a total beginner so sorry if I'm just bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is occuring because both of your objects need a `Collider2D` and a `Rigidbody2D` in order for collider events to fire.

Also, this tutorial is really poor and if you are really trying to make a game, I would suggest finding a new one. He teaches concepts that are "hacky" and are not scaleable.